# Installing ROS Indigo on Ubuntu 14.04.2

Tags: ros

**System Information:**

No LSB modules are available.

Distributor ID: Ubuntu

Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS

Release:    14.04

Codename:   trusty

**Error message we get:**

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
ros-indigo-desktop-full : Depends: ros-indigo-desktop but it is not going to be installed
                          Depends: ros-indigo-perception but it is not going to be installed
                          Depends: ros-indigo-simulators but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

If I explore the error message further, this is what I get:

```
ros-indigo-cpp-common : Depends: libconsole-bridge0.2 but it is not installable
                        Depends: libboost-all-dev but it is not installable
                        Depends: libconsole-bridge-dev but it is not installable
```

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully installed ROS Indigo on Ubuntu 14.04. So be assured that it can be done.

I have seen many of these errors when installing ROS packages. There seems to be some error in the package management system in Ubuntu (aptitude). You may try

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -f
```

If it doesn't work, try to manually install some dependencies by

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-simulators
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-perception
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to delete the old installation as manual installations of dependencies may be too much. I have written a complete end to end [blog](https://www.mierobot.com/single-post/ROS-Robot-UbuntuInstallation) on the installation of ROS Indigo over Ubuntu 14.04.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For those whom still had problems after trying everything.

I have tracked dependencies and found out that the problem is libboost, I had the version 1.55 but some of ros-indigo modules require the 1.54 version 
Try these commands

```
 sudo apt-get install libboost1.54-tools-dev
 sudo apt-get install libboost-tools-dev
 sudo apt-get install libboost-mpi-python1.54.0
 sudo apt-get install libboost-mpi-python1.54-dev
 sudo apt-get install libboost-mpi-python-dev
```

then you can finally

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-desktop-full
```

Hope this helps