# ROS Installation E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, ros

I am trying to install ROS Indigo. I did the following steps:

```
$ sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'

$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-key 421C365BD9FF1F717815A3895523BAEEB01FA116

$ sudo apt-get update

$ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-desktop-full
```

When I executed the last line, I've received the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-indigo-desktop-full : Depends: ros-indigo-desktop but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-indigo-perception but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-indigo-simulators but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-indigo-urdf-tutorial but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45606925/8977639) suggested solution, however it did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Cannot Install ROS Indigo On Ubuntu 16.04 Officially With apt-get Cause It's Compatible with Ubuntu 14.04 (and I think Ubuntu 14.10)

However There are Workaround For Installing But Its not Recommended

Official Release For Ubuntu 16.04 Is Kinetic, Which Is The latest LTS Version

Answer (score 0):

Try using to handle the error:

```
sudo get upgrade
```